# What of Mei Terumi, the 5th Mizukage's marriage?

Tags: naruto

Mei Terumi, the 5th Mizukage is always angry and tensed at the thought of marriage.

Who does she marry anyway? Does Chojuro get her?

Comment: This question is not duplicate.It has not been answered on the link to the question provided.Please, moderators,do not trash a question like this before interpreting the complete meaning.

Comment: The "original" question that you claim does not have any references to Mei Terumi.

Comment: To all the future readers,please nominate the question to reopen for answering.

Comment: The dupe mentioned all the known marriages. Other than that, it's never stated and there's only speculation/fan theory which is outside of the Q&A scope.

Answer (score -5):

It's because she's not married yet in spite of her age, at least in Naruto Shippuden.

**It's very common in many Asian cultures that an unmarried woman would be angry if somebody mentioned something related to marriage, especially when she's about 28 and up y.o**. It's like if you ask "how much do you weigh?" to a woman.

I don't know about her marital status in Boruto.