# What happened to Metal Lee's Mother?

Tags: boruto

Metal lee is Rock lee's son and that is pretty obvious based of the similarities between both of them but what about his Mother?

[image]

At first, I thought it was Tenten because she seemed like the "best available option", but then, since she has not really been an active "mother figure", I'm guessing that's not the case.  And if she were his mother then she would have been more involved in his life. Except maybe there's a basis for her absence?

> ***Also, is there a reason why his Mother's identity is not elaborated on?***

Comment: While I would agree it is more specific, [other related (and more specific) questions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/48860/what-of-mei-terumi-the-5th-mizukages-marriage) have been closed as dups as well. As far as I am aware, the answer in the linked question is still accurate

Comment: That seems pretty restrictive if you ask me @Wondercricket multiple questions on the same characters can be asked as long as they are different but of course there could be related in sense, but that does not make it a duplicate. I believe that question is actually not a duplicate too. Cause in both cases, the question was asking something completely different, plus the answer did not answer that question.

Comment: Per your latest edit, I went ahead and retracted my close vote. "Who is Metal's mother" is different than "What happened to her". Sorry for just now getting to that, I'm at work :). Somebody else still may consider it a dup, but that's for them to decide

Answer (score 2):

As of now, *there is no official information who it is or what happened to her*, only rumors and theories. One such [theory](https://www.quora.com/Who-is-the-mother-of-Metal-Lee-and-Rock-Lees-wife) is that it was Tenten. From what I found, a Boruto movie's credits showed the following picture with the new characters together with their parents at the back. One could say that it might be Tenten. [image]

As for official information, this the only thing I found, [a tweet with no hints at all](https://www.tumblr.com/search/rock%20lee%20wife). 
[image]

There is also a cotnradicting 'information' circulating the Internet that *Kishimoto said in an interview that he has not yet drawn Metal Lee's mother* when asked if Tenten was Metal Lee's mtoher. This was posted in many sites but without linking sources to the interview itself, apart from a [Tumblr post](https://web.archive.org/web/20151013021553/http://cacatuasulphureacitrinocristata.tumblr.com:80/post/126215560096/was-it-revealed-in-the-movie-whether-tenten-is) that claims Kishimoto said it in an interview. A [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/3gb7u4/so_apparently_tenten/) claims that the one who posted the Tumblr post was 'a reliable translator in the Naruto fandom' but since *the original Tumblr post was long deleted with no sources at all*, I'm finding it real hard to believe this. I'm thinking this is not true as of now due to lack of evidence.

To conclude, **we definitely cannot say for sure who Metal Lee's mother is or what happened to her**, given the current information and the manga chapters released.

Comment: you have a point in the movie credits part but then where is Orochimaru? cause he should be at the back of mitsuki right?

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin I think the point of the credits photo was to show us, the viewing audience, the people we cared about, and their lives after Shippuuden. It doesn't technically confirm Tenten is Metal Lee's mother, but it certainly implies as much. Can you imagine how awkward it would look to randomly have Orochimaru standing next to Naruto/Hinata in that photo? You also don't see Temari next to Shikamaru because she wasn't part of the original Naruto Konoha Genin cast. Sai of course is included because he later joins Team 7.